# Steam Play and Nvidia drivers

Tags: graphic-drivers, nvidia, steam

Having been excited by the newest release of steam play by Valve I hurried and try it out on my eOS machine. 
I installed Doom (2016) and noticed with great disappointment that it flickers in a way that it is playable.

Then, I read online that Steam Play need Nvidia drivers 39X.Xx, whereas on the Debian repository we have 386.xx. 
Steam play is in Beta so this lag in drivers update is understandable but I was wondering if it is creating issues to you too

Answer (score 1):

You can grab the latest proprietary NVidia drivers from:

[https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa](https://launchpad.net/%7Egraphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa)

To add the PPA you will need to install software-properties-common with:

> sudo apt install software-properties-common

Then:

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
>
> sudo apt update

For the latest (short lived) NVidia driver:

> sudo apt install nvidia-396

Comment: Thanks! That did it! Can you solve my question about PPAs? If we can install update drivers/ software, why wouldn't the elementary team / ubuntu install them directly in their repository?

Comment: It's probably about stability. The Elementary team will always use the driver that is proven to be rock solid stable. Luckily for gamer's, we always have this option to install the latest and greatest drivers.